# Using parse to retrieve and show user's object in tableview but tableview won't update

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

Here is my code in swift

```
class UserViewController: UITableViewController {

var userArray: [String] = []

@IBOutlet weak var friendListTableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       retrieveMessages()
       self.friendListTableView.reloadData()


   }
func retrieveMessages() {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    if let username = PFUser.currentUser().username {
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        for object in objects! {
            let usernames:String? = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String
            if usernames != nil {
                self.userArray.append(usernames!)
            }
        }

    }

}
}
            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return userArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Update - replace as with as!

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

My `UITableView` won't update. I've changed where the `self.friendListTableView.reloadData()` is located from inside retrieveMessage function to inside the `viewDidLoad` method and the table's still empty. I believe that my method in `retrieveMessage()` is incorrect somehow, probably inside `for object in objects { ... }`.

Here's a screenshot of my "User" class in parse 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xp48v3yn0l2hje/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.13%20PM.png?dl=0
and here's my current user's relation table  saved by PFRelation method
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd8mt8sf35u1m0v/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.55%20PM.png?dl=0

Any help is appreciated and let me know if you need any additional information. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you mark in the storyboard that your UserViewController is dataSource and delegate for tableView? i mean this: [dataSource and delegate for tableView](http://s1.postimg.org/hpc3rcqun/Screen_Shot_2015_06_05_at_12_54_17.png)

2) and i think you mast past reload of tableView here:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects, error) -> Void in

    for object in objects! {
        let usernames:String? = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String
        if usernames != nil {
            self.userArray.append(usernames!)
        }
    }dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
friendListTableView.reloadData()
```

}}

Comment: It didn't work. I forgot to mark my userViewController as dataSource and delegate so I did it and I've my code with your code, still the tableview is still empty and I don't know why. Please help

Comment: UPDATE: my method didn't grab object at all the problem must be with how I declare usernames variable but how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to call `reloadData` on your table after populating your array.

After this:

```
for object in objects! {
   let usernames:String? = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String
   if usernames != nil {
       self.userArray.append(usernames!)
   }
}
```

You need this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.friendListTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I've tried and it still didn't work, the tableview is still empty. I've tried almost everything here, please help.

Comment: Does your method actually grab objects? Let's verify by, for example, putting `println(usernames)` just before `if usernames != nil`; or put a breakpoint on `if usernames != nil` and inspect the `usernames` property in the debugger.

Comment: It says nil, but I'm sure there's friend list in current user's account, what cause this? did I declare it wrong somehow?

Comment: I tried it and now it's full of error, not quite sure where to go.Can you point me what should I fix? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` runs in the background (as the name suggests). From the [documentation for `PFQuery`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:):

> Finds objects asynchronously and calls the given block with the
>   results.

Therefore `userArray` won't be populated by the time you call `friendListTableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad`. According to [How can I populate a UITableView with data from a parse.com query after it is done running in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335596/how-can-i-populate-a-uitableview-with-data-from-a-parse-com-query-after-it-is-do), you should do the following in `retrieveMessages`:

```
//...

for object in objects! {
    // You can shorten the code in your for-loop to:
    if let usernames = (object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String {
        self.userArray.append(usernames)
    }
}

// Here userArray has been updated so it's a good time to call reloadData().
// (You should always update UI on the main thread)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    friendListTableView.reloadData()
}

//...
```

If you're unfamiliar with `dispatch_async`, I would recommend you take a look at the [Developing iOS 8 Apps With Swift Lectures](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099) on iTunesU, there's a good one on multithreading.

Comment: I do exactly as you say and it didn't work probably the problem with usernames variable, I might have declared it wrong somehow but I don't know how to fix it.I'm stuck with this problem almost a week  and I don't know what to do now . Please help

Comment: Have you checked `userArray` contains anything by the time you're calling `reloadData`? I would also check `(object as PFObject)["Friends"] as? String` doesn't return `nil`.

Comment: UPDATE: my method didn't grab object at all the problem must be  with how I declare usernames variable but how to fix it? Thanks